# Change direction of a CSS transition

Tags: html, css, transition

I would like to make the buttons move left so they don’t hit with the right margin and move, but I don't know how.

Can someone explain how to change the direction of the transition?

```css
.menus {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.menus ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menus ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.menus ul li .icon-home3 { background: #81e0cd; }
.menus ul li .icon-terminal { background: #81e0cd; }
.menus ul li .icon-pacman { background: #81e0cd; }

.menus ul li a:hover {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='menus'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-home3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-terminal"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-pacman"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How can somebody tell you without HTML ?

Comment: The answer has little to do with transitions. Your real question is “when I increase an element's width (by adding padding), how can I make that element extend farther to the left instead of to the right?” The answer to that is to right-align the elements, using `text-align: right;` or Flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `text-align` property to move the items to the right. I also changed the `padding` property to `width` , since we want to modify the width anyway.

The changes are applied to the item onHover event. So, we start with the standard size of the element e.g. `20px` and then let it grow to `100%` or `whatever size` you like.

As others already wrote in the comment section, feel free to use `flexbox` as an alternative.

```css
    .menus {
      position: fixed;
      right: 40;
      top: 150px;
      z-index: 2000;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    
    .menus ul {
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: right;
      padding: 10px 0 5px;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    
    .menus ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      background: #000;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
      transition: all .3s ease;
    }
    
    .menus ul li .icon-home3 {
      background: #81e0cd;
    }
    
    .menus ul li .icon-terminal {
      background: #81e0cd;
    }
    
    .menus ul li .icon-pacman {
      background: #81e0cd;
    }
    
    .menus ul li:hover a {
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
    }
```

```html
<div class='menus'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-home3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-terminal"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-pacman"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacky way of doing it but it might you.

Change your `padding: 10px 25px` into `transform: scaleX(1.6)` you can input whatever value you want.

```css
.menus {
  position: fixed;
  right: 40;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.menus ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.menus ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.menus ul li .icon-home3 { background: #81e0cd; }
.menus ul li .icon-terminal { background: #81e0cd; }
.menus ul li .icon-pacman { background: #81e0cd; }

.menus ul li a:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.6);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='menus'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-home3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-terminal"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="icon-pacman"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```